# How do I combine Sympy expressions with strings without having the formatting get messed up?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, formatting, ipython, sympy

I'm using Sympy to do several symbolic computations in a Jupyter Notebook and I want to be able to get outputs of the form "x = [sympy expression] = [sympy expression]".  If I just do something like

```
    from sympy import symbols, diff
    x = symbols('x')
    y = diff(6*x**5)
    y
```

It will display the value of `y` using nice textbook style notation.  The problem is if I try to combine text with Sympy expressions.  If I simply put a Sympy expression in a print statement, it doesn't preserve the formatting but will display the result using standard Python syntax (I've tried using `pprint` and all of Sympy's other print functions, but they didn't help).  If I instead use the `display` function from IPython, that renders the Sympy expressions correctly, but it will also put them on separate lines from the text.  So, for instance, if I do

```
   display(f"y ={y}")
```

the "y =" will be on a separate line from the expression for y.  If I have several Sympy expressions in one `display` statement, that results in things being needlessly broken up into several lines, which is a rather ugly output.

The only way I found around the unwanted line breaks is to wrap the Sympy expressions in IPython's `Math` function, which seems to convert the Sympy expressions to regular Python syntax (e.g. x² becomes x**2), then use regular expressions to convert the Python syntax to LaTex syntax, which the `Math` function will render properly (e.g. `display(f'y = {re.sub('\*\*', '^', Math(y)}')`). It works, but it's a lot of hassle.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I figured it out, so I'm posting my solution in case anyone else has a similar question:  the need for directly using regular expressions to convert the sympy expression to LaTex the `Math` can render can be avoided by using Sympy's LaTex function, which converts any sympy expression to LaTex syntax.  So, doing, e.g.

```
from IPython.display import display, Math
from sympy import latex, symbols, diff
    x = symbols('x')
    y = diff(6*x**5)

display(Math(f' y = {latex(y)}'))
```

will give the single line output:

y = 30x⁴

which is exactly what I wanted (albeit, for more complicated expressions than the one I gave as an example).